# How to use Nested Form Fields in Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a component called `project-form` and in that again I am calling another component called `search-users`. The problem is that I am unable to set the `$members` property in `ProjectForm` from nested component i.e `search-users`.

As I can understand `$members` must be looking to set in `SearchUsers.php` but I want that must be set in `ProjectForm.php` so I could save in db.

**project-form.blade.php**

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
   <input wire:model="name"/>
   <input wire:model="category"/>
   <input wire:model="target_date"/>

   @livewire('search-users')
</form>
```

**ProjectForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Project;
use Livewire\Component;

class ProjectForm extends Component
{

    public string $name = '';
    public string $category = '';
    public string $target_date = '';
    public array $members = [];
    
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'target_date' => 'required',
    ];

    public function submit(){
        
        $validated = $this->validate();
        Project::create($validated);
        toastr()->success('Project Created Successfully');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.project-form');
    }
}
```

**search-users.blade.php**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <label class="list-group-item ps-0 border-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img alt="{{ $user->name }}" src="{{ url('storage/'.$user->avatar) }}" width="35" class="me-3 rounded-circle mx-auto d-block">
            {{ $user->name }}
        </div>
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" wire:model.defer="members" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}">
    </label>
@endforeach
```

Comment: To communicate between components, you need to emit an event from your search component, and listen to it in the form component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggestes by @Qirel you should use [Livewire events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#firing-events).

In your search components you could emit an event `memebersFound` and passing the members from your search as parameter (see Livewire [Passing parameters in events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#passing-parameters)) like this

```
$this->emit('membersFound', $membersFound);
```

Then, in your ProjectForm component you should listen for this event

```php
protected $listeners = [
  'membersFound' => 'addMembers'
];

public function addMembers(array $members)
{
  $this->members = $members;
}
```